# AJAX call to php not returning value when using post method

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

PHP Code

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "ngram";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $uid =$_REQUEST["username"];
    $sql = 'select * from user_db where username like '.'"'.$uid.'"';
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    //echo $sql;
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        $conn->close();
        echo (0);
    }
    else 
    {   
        $conn->query("insert into user_db values('".$_REQUEST["name"]."','".$_REQUEST["username"]."','".$_REQUEST["email"]."','".$_REQUEST["pass"]."')");
        $conn->close();
        echo (1);
    }
```

?>

```
function connectDb(formElement)
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST","signup.php",true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send(new FormData (formElement));
}
function myFunction(response)
{   
    if(response != 1)
    {
        window.open("error.html","_self");
    }
    else
    {
        window.open("login.html","_self");
    }
}
```

Here javascript is able to send request but php is not returning any value. The values gets added to the database but the page does not changes. Only returned value gets displayed in screen.

Comment: You are using both "xmlhttp" and "xhttp" in your javascript. I believe you need to use "xmlhttp" everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

you write `return $r` but not write a function for access it.write a function or either write `echo $r;`.

Comment: i have tried with `echo $r` but it just prints it in a new page.